# draw images with random rotation java + processing

Tags: java, processing

I'm drawing arrows using Java and I can draw them straight but now I need to have the arrows pointing in different directions.

In my current code, I draw a triangle and then a square.

Is there a way to group the two after they've been drawn and then rotate them at a random angle?

Right now I'm only able to rotate the triangle and square separately, causing some messy thing.

```
void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
}

void draw() {
  float r = random(24, 64);
  background(255);
 
  drawArrow(r);
  //drawPlus(r);
  saveFrame("dataArrow/plus####.png");

  if (frameCount == 100) {
    exit();
  }
}

void drawArrow(float r){
  float base = r * 2;
  float xStart = random(1, width-base - 1);
  float xEnd = xStart + base;
  float k = 0.5 * base;
  float y = random(k, width-k);
  float middleBase = base/2 + xStart;
  float rectSide = 0.5 * base;
  float rectX1 = middleBase - rectSide/2;
  float rectX2 = middleBase + rectSide/2;
  fill(0);
  triangle(xStart, y, xEnd, y, middleBase,  y - k);
  rect(rectX1, y, rectSide, rectSide);
}
```

Comment: this is java. what library are you using?

Comment: Your TAG was wrong and removed it. Your title was not

Comment: i mean it uses java at a base but its in a program called processing. theres probably a bunch of stuff in the backend because this just works in processing

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this exactly what you mean but here is how to move things around

push and pop matrix allows you to organize things that should have the same translations

https://processing.org/reference/pushMatrix_.html

https://processing.org/reference/rotate_.html

https://processing.org/reference/translate_.html

basic example

```
pushMatrix();//start of new translation and rotation things
translate(xAmount,yAmount);//this moves the origin
rotate(angle);//this rotates around origin
//drawing around the point of rotation 0,0 here
//drawing...
popMatrix();//reset all translations and rotations to before
```